# Me da error en arreglo ya que se indica que esta en 0 pero no se como cambiar eso o bien que pasa

Tags: javascript, java, array, objeto, pilas

Según tengo entendido se da porque en el arreglo al intentar hacer el método se indica como si no existe nada pero no se como solucionarlo, lo que quiero hacer es que el arreglo vaya agregando los datos en la pila que el usuario desee usando el método push de la clase pila.

Por cierto el código aun no esta acabado pero necesito esa parte para hacer las demás partes

error NetBeans/Cache/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53

Clase principal

public class Principal {

```
public static int leerEntero(String mensaje, int min, int max) {
    Scanner ingreso = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dato = 0;
    do {
        System.out.println(mensaje);
        dato = ingreso.nextInt();
    } while (dato < min || dato > max);
    return dato;
}

public static String leerString(String mensaje) {
    Scanner ingreso = new Scanner(System.in);
    String dato = "";
    System.out.println(mensaje);
    dato = ingreso.nextLine();
    return dato;
}

public static int menu() {
    System.out.println("Menu");
    System.out.println("1. Insertar una caja");
    System.out.println("2. Buscar caja");
    System.out.println("3. Sacar caja");
    System.out.println("4. Salir");
    return leerEntero("Seleccione una opcion ",1,4);
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int opcion = 0;
    int pila=1;
    int max=3;
    Pila[] p1= new Pila[3];
    do {
        opcion = menu();
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                pila=leerEntero("Existe "+max+" filas elija una de ellas",1,max);
                System.out.println("Ingrese la caja que desea insertar");
                Caja obj = new Caja(
                        leerEntero("Ingrese el codigo: ",0,1000000),
                        leerString("Ingrese el nombre de la empresa: "));
                p1[pila].push(obj);
                break;
            case 2:
                /*try {
                    Caja atendido = p1.pop();
                    System.out.println(atendido.toString());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
                break;*/
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Listado de estudiante en la cola");
                //p1.imprimir();
                break;
        }
    } while (opcion != 4);
}
```

}

Clase pila

public class Pila {

```
private Nodo cima;
private int lim = 0;

public Pila() {
    cima = null;
}

public boolean esVacia() {
    return cima == null;
}

public boolean limite() {
    return lim == 6;
}

public boolean verificarCodigo(int codigo) {
    if (esVacia()) {
        return false;
    }
    Nodo aux = cima;
    while (aux != null) {
        if (aux.getDato().getCodigo() == codigo) {
            return true;
        }
        aux = aux.getSiguiente();
    }
    return false;
}

public void push(Caja dato) {
    if (verificarCodigo(dato.getCodigo()) == true) {
        System.out.println("No se puede insertar porque el codigo existe!");
    } else {
        if (limite() == true) {
            System.out.println("Pila llena");
        } else {
            lim++;
            Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(dato, cima);
            cima = nuevo;
        }
    }
}

public Caja pop() throws Exception {
    if (esVacia()) {
        throw new Exception("Esta vacia");
    }
    Nodo aux = cima;
    cima = cima.getSiguiente();
    aux.setSiguiente(null);
    return aux.getDato();
}

public void imprimir() {
    if (esVacia()) {
        System.out.println("Esta vacia");
    } else {
        Nodo aux = cima;
        while (aux != null) {
            System.out.println(aux.getDato().toString());
            aux = aux.getSiguiente();
        }
    }
}
```

}

si necesitan las otras clases que uso estas son
Clase nodo
public class Nodo {

```
private Caja dato;
private Nodo siguiente;

public Nodo(Caja dato, Nodo siguiente) {
    this.dato = dato;
    this.siguiente = siguiente;
}

public Caja getDato() {
    return dato;
}

public void setDato(Caja dato) {
    this.dato = dato;
}

public Nodo getSiguiente() {
    return siguiente;
}

public void setSiguiente(Nodo siguiente) {
    this.siguiente = siguiente;
}
```

}

Clase Caja

public class Caja {

```
private int codigo;
private String empresa;

public Caja(int codigo, String empresa) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.empresa = empresa;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getEmpresa() {
    return empresa;
}

public void setEmpresa(String empresa) {
    this.empresa = empresa;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Caja"
            + "\nCodigo: " + codigo
            + "\nEmpresa:" + empresa;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

En tu código usas 3 pilas. Y las inicialisas así:

```
Pila[] p1= new Pila[3];
```

Eso crea un arreglo de 3 pilas. Y cada pila se queda con un valor nulo.
Eso te debe generar un problema en la linea:

```
p1[pila].push(obj);
```

Para solucionarlo veo dos opciones (pudiera haber más):

a) Crear el arreglo de pilas e inicializar sus 3 elementos al mismo tiempo:

Es decir hacer:

```
   Pila[] p1= new Pila[]{ new Pila(), new Pila(), new Pila()} ;
```

b) Crear el arreglo e iterar tantas veces como elementos tiene haciendo un new y asignandolo. Es decir hacer:

```
   Pila[] p1= new Pila[3];

   for( int indice = 0 ; indice < 3 ; indice++)
   {
      p1[indice] = new Pila();
   }
```

Estoy entendiendo que el primer case del switch lo que busca es escoger una de las tres pilas para meter una caja y que el segundo switch también elegirá una de las tres pilas para sacar una caja.

Quedo atento a tus comentarios, avísame si te sirvió lo que te coloque.

Comment: Gracias con ese método lo acabo de arreglar, muchas gracias